# How to run a process in the background inside Gvim?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

Well, what I need to do actually is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> out of a process that got started from insert mode in `GVim`.

My command `:Cdprun` executes `cdprun.sh` which runs a sudo-ed daemon. I can add `&` at the end of the sudo-ed daemon call to run in the background and that works but the user doesn't get prompted for a password. Instead I want to just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> out of it but the keyboard interrupt doesn't work. Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Why do you need a keyboard interrupt? To abort the daemon or come back Gvim while the daemon is running?

Answer (score 2):

You generally have two options in this case: generic is using something like vim-addon-async mentioned by @Nicalas Martin or vim with built-in interpreters support: tcl with expect module, python with pyexpect, perl with Expect, maybe something else (note: all of the mentioned packages are not shipped with tcl/python/perl). Second is specific to current situation: it is backgrounding in the other place. From your explanation I guessed that you have a script looking like

```
#!/bin/sh
<...>
sudo run-daemon --daemon-args # Last executed line
```

, am I right? Than you can just put backgrounding in another place: not

```
sudo run-daemon --daemon-args &
```

, but

```
sudo sh -c "nohup run-daemon --daemon-args &"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to deal with asynchronous command in vim. Not a perfect solution but could be a good temporary solution. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3307